# onActivityResult not working in React Native Module with custom Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, react-native

I want to get the result data from my custom Activity in my React Native Module, but currently, my `onActivityResult` function never getting that data.

Currently my react module looks like this:

```
class VideoEditorModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) 
    : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext), ActivityEventListener {

    ...

    override fun onActivityResult(
        activity: Activity,
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent
    ) {
        val data = data.data

        Log.d("ReactModule", "onActivityResult " + data.toString())
    }

   override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    val data = intent?.data
    Log.d("ReactModule", "onNewIntent: " + data.toString())
   }

   @ReactMethod
   fun openNativeVideoEditor(videoURL: String, promise: Promise) {
      reactApplicationContext.addActivityEventListener(this)

    val currentActivity = currentActivity;

    if (currentActivity == null) {
        promise.reject("ERROR_ACTIVITY", "Activity doesn't exist");
        return;
    }

    modulePromise = promise
    
    val intent = Intent(currentActivity, VideoEditorActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("videoURL", videoURL)
    
    try {
        currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK, null)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        promise.reject("ERROR_ACTIVITY", e);
        modulePromise = null;
    }
   }

}
```

The native activity looks like:

```
class VideoEditorActivity: AppCompatActivity(), OnEditVideoListener {
    ...

    override fun getResult(uri: Uri) {
        Log.d("VideoEditorActivity", "getResult ${uri.path}")

        val i = intent
        i.putExtra("Resulted", uri.path)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i)

        finish()
    }
}
```

Module successfully opens the activity, the activity works, I can edit my video but when I complete my editing, my `getResult` log prints the new URL for the edited video but looks like the result setup before `finish()` is not working. `onActivityResult` in my module doesn't log anything in Android Studio.

Many thanks for each help with this.

RN version 0.64.1

Comment: Have you found the solutin?

Comment: does this work if you make this an abstract class?